# Bash loop script PHP with auto increment variable

Tags: php, linux, bash

I'm trying to do a Bash script like:

```
n=1; While(n<=500) php /Path/script.php?v=$n ++n;
```

I would like to these script run in parallel. It could use so much of CPU? Or maybe parallel wouldn't be good?

Comment: What is in script.php? That's the deciding factor of whether or not it's a good idea to run it 500 times at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple bash solution is to use the for construct and send the current instance of said script to the background, like this:

```
for n in {1..500}; do
    php /Path/script.php?v=$n &
done
```

This will make it so that it's ran 500 times in *parallel*, whether it's going to use up all of your resources or not depends on what resources are available and what the script does.

I for one, doubt that this is an ideal solution, but it depends on what you're trying to achieve and what the reason for wanting to do it this way is.

Comment: Im doing this same thing with php multicurl but it eat alot of cpu, maybe doing in this way could be better.

Comment: is there a way to "echo" something after each script finish?

Comment: Um, yes, you can use the **wait** built in, see my edit for more details

Comment: I had something completely different in mind, I guess you're looking for something other than the "[1]     Done" Message